# AutoHotKey Copy Paste between windows

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to copy and paste between a Excell file and firefox browser the username and password, but when it switches back to the excel file, it's not copying the password, and pastes the username in the password field.

^z::

{

```
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{RIGHT}{ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}
sleep, 300
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{TAB}{ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}
sleep, 500
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}
sleep, 500
Send, {ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}
Sleep, 300
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{TAB}{SPACE}
```

}

return

Comment: Try to replace the AltTab command with the commands WinActivate, WinWaitActive.

Comment: Storing passwords in unencrypted containers generally sounds like a bad idea. Please consider using a password safe utility like KeePass. KeePass also supports several methods of automatic password insertion, e.g. auto-typing user credentials based on the active window's title.

Comment: -- AutoHotkey can candle COM (Component Object Model), i.e. Excel macros, so you could retrieve text directly from Excel, and only have to look at Firefox.
-- For a less direct solution, `WinActivate` beats alt+tab and using `ClipWait` pauses the script until a ctrl+c copy command is completed.
-- Also potentially you could store some/all information in an ini or text file and retrieve that programmatically via `IniRead`/`FileRead`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try it:

```
#c:: 
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}
sleep, 300
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}{ENTER}{ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}
return
```